# Extranational : existence ou fiction ?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Je cherchais à exprimer l'idée d'un évènement ayant des répercussions aussi au niveau national qu'*à l'extérieur du territoire national*. En cette occurrence, j'ai voulu utiliser le mot *extranational*.

> **extranational** : en dehors, au-delà du territoire national.

On trouve ce type de définition dans le dictionnaire Reverso en ligne, mais pas dans le Larousse (auquel je ne cache pas accorder plus de confiance). Ni l'édition en ligne du Larousse ni l'édition papier 2013 chez moi n'affichent ce mot.

En revanche, une recherche Google révèle quelques utilisations par des auteurs plus ou moins reconnus. De même, le mot est présent dans plusieurs dictionnaires de français.

Alors, extranational est-il français ?

Comment: C'est tout simplement le mot anglais "extra(-)national" qui est alors francisé. Quant à sa légitimité c'est sûrement à débattre. Du moment que c'est compris, ça ne devrait pas poser de problème.

Comment: à l'extérieur du territoire national c'est l'inverse de: à intérieur du territoire national

Comment: [(d') outre(-)frontière](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extra-national%2Cextranational%2Coutre-fronti%C3%A8re%2Coutre+fronti%C3%A8re&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextra%20-%20national%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextranational%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutre%20-%20fronti%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coutre%20fronti%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0) is still slightly ahead of "extranational" and ["qu'outre-frontière"](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/bhvf/outre-fronti%C3%A8re) could be nearly synonymous with "qu'à l'extérieur du territoire national" in this context.

Answer (score 4):

En effet, je n'ai pas trouvé de définition pour extranational dans le Larousse. 
Je pense que le mot "international" est plus approprié ou plus utilisé dans ce cas.

Exemple: avec ses répercussions aux niveaux economique, national et international.

Vous pourriez aussi dire: "ayant des répercussions aussi bien en France qu'à l'étranger."

Comment: J'ai bien pensé à international, mais celui ci inclut tout de suite l'idée d'une implication mondiale, ce que je ne cherche pas forcément (par exemple, si je cherche à dire que telle évènement n'a pas seulement de répercussion en France mais également en Europe (et non dans le monde))

Answer (score 2):

Je n'utiliserais pas ***extranational*** pour « aussi (autant) au niveau national qu'à l'extérieur du territoire national » car *extranational* signifie plutôt « en dehors de toute influence ou considération liées aux nations ».

Pour décrire un événement affectant à la fois une nation et l'extérieur de son territoire, je le qualifierais simplement de global. Voir par exemple cet [article](https://www.cairn.info/revue-hermes-la-revue-2006-3-page-13.htm) 
***Arquembourg Jocelyne***, « De l'événement international à **l'événement global** : émergence et manifestations d'une sensibilité mondiale », Hermès, La Revue, 3/2006 (n° 46), p. 13-21.

Si, en revanche, l'influence de l'événement n'est pas aussi large que celle qu'implique « global », il est possible de dire :

> Un événement dont l'influence **déborde nos frontières**.